# Spark implicits do not work on dbutils object

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-connect

Why cannot I do somthing like this?

```
import spark.implicits._
dbutils.fs.ls(folderName).toDF
```

throws an error of

```
value toDF is not a member of Seq[com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FileInfo]
```

But it works fine in databricks notebook. Can anyone advice what I am missing?

I am using the following library
"com.databricks" %% "dbutils-api" % "0.0.4"

Answer (score 1):

From the relevant [Databricks page](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html):

> DBUtils are not supported outside of notebooks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am just creating a jar to be used inside databricks.